# how to use Instrumentation under the uiautomator project?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

I'm working on a uiautomator project recently and then the UiObject.getFromParent turn out a wrong element to me and I look into the source code of uiautomator and found out the answer is because by the UiSelector I used.

I found that the uiautomator is using the Instrumentation to get the UI element stuff just like :

```
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().getRootInActiveWindow();
```

I just want to get a AccessibilityNodeInfo node just like what uiautomator do but the uiautomator didn't exposed this.

I’m trying this way by a new class extends InstrumentationTestCase,by the getInstrumentation() always return a null to me.

i found an answer on
 [android instrumentation test case - getinstrumentation() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678959/android-instrumentation-test-case-getinstrumentation-returning-null) 
 that needs `injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());`
 and told InstrumentationRegistry is from the official Android testing-support-lib:0.1

I have download the Android Support Repository and import the testing-support-lib-0.1-source.jar into my project but I still can't see InstrumentationRegistry.

Anyone have any idea about my cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Frist tried:

i have noticed that the point of this question is the uiautomator didn't expose the api i want,and when i look into the source and found the UiDevice.dumpWindowHierarchy that has these code:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo root =getAutomatorBridge().getQueryController().getAccessibilityRootNode();
 the getAutomatorBridge was implemented by UiDevice:
   UiAutomatorBridge getAutomatorBridge() {
        if (mUiAutomationBridge == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("UiDevice not initialized");
        }
        return mUiAutomationBridge;
    }
```

the point is there is no modifier on it,so what i have done is modified it's modifier to public ,modified the byte code of

> /system/framework/uiautomator.jar

and the other one in sdk(sorry i don't,ya it worked!i can use it like this.

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo root =getUidevice().getAutomatorBridge().getQueryController().getAccessibilityRootNode();
```

but there is a compatibility issue isn't it?

### Second tried:

Let's think about the default modifier of java,we can access it under the same package,so why don't we just implement a class has the same Package name ?then we can call it without any unnomal patch.
that's what i have done and it really works well:

```
package com.android.uiautomator.core;

import android.view.Display;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

public class AutomationUltilites
{
    public AutomationUltilites()
    {
    }
    public static AccessibilityNodeInfo  getRootNode()
    {
        return UiDevice.getInstance().getAutomatorBridge().getRootInActiveWindow();
    }
    public static Display getDisplay()
    {
        return UiDevice.getInstance().getAutomatorBridge().getDefaultDisplay();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an extension of InstrumentationTestCase and it works just fine like this:

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    AccessibilityNodeInfo root = instrumentation.getUiAutomation().getRootInActiveWindow();
}
```

I imported

```
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
```

and installed

```
Android Support Repository (15)
Android Support Library (22.2)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer yes it helped and i'm very appreciate,but my project is using the extension of UiAutomatorTestCase and i have already written  a lot of code  base on it,so i don't want to change it.and in the end i have solved this question in a little bit unnormal way what i marked as acceptance of answer.and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

well,this question has beep solved by

> unpack testing-support-lib-0.1.aar and get the classes.jar instead of
>   testing-support-lib-0.1-source.jar

.and now the eclipse will not saying can't resolved anymore.By the way,u have to

> add this lib to Ant's javac classpath by edit build.xml

or else u will get a lib not found while u trying ant build.
but now the NEW question has turns out

`INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry;`

maybe it's another question so i am going to find out via google and i will update this if figure it out or i will post a new question.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Eclipse  but AndroidStudio. I had tons of problems when I tried to use Eclipse and after figuring out Android Studio it worked like a charm :)